# xsd element type based on number of occurances

Tags: xsd

I have the following xml

```
<Root>
    <custom_fields>
        <name_key>additional_locations</name_key>
            <value>California</value>
            <value>Texas</value>
    </custom_fields>
    <custom_fields>
        <name_key>cost_center</name_key>
        <value>IT</value>
    </custom_fields>
</Root>
```

I would like to create a XML schema to generate the following JSON Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Root": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "custom_fields": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "name_key": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "value": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": [
                    {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "name_key",
                "value"
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "name_key": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "value": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "name_key",
                "value"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "custom_fields"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Root"
  ]
}
```

JSON schema gives the following JSON

```
{
    "Root": {
        "custom_fields": [
            {
                "name_key": "additional_locations",
                "value": [
                    "California",
                    "Texas"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name_key": "cost_center",
                "value": "IT"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried something like this

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="custom_fields" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                    minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name_key" />
                            <xs:choice>
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value" maxOccurs="1"
                                    minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                    minOccurs="2" />
                            </xs:choice>        
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Any help is highly appreciated, thx.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. An XML schema does not _generate_ anything. It _describes_ an XML document. It can be used to _describe_ a wide variety of logical data structures. But it cannot _generate_ JSON.

Comment: Ok I just need schema to validate this xml

Comment: In that case, please edit your question and remove any reference to the JSON.

Comment: Please also explain what your question is. Asking for 'help' is too broad, and will get downvoted by less patient people than me ( why is that XSD not doing the job for you? )